# No plural forms for suspension message

Tags: bug, status-declined, account-suspension, localization, plurals

I found the [message](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16848) in traducir that definitely needs plural forms for "daysToken" variable:

> Your account has been temporarily suspended for $daysToken$ days. While you’re suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once the suspension ends.

Could this please be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is going to be a tough one that we wont be able to get to right now. The reason is that in this case, the `$daysToken$` itself is a token that is to be used for a client-side substitution. (For context, this is for the mod message editor, where different template messages are provided). Our multi-lingual string processing requires an actual number (and not a string token called `$days$`) in order to be set up with plural forms. So unfortunately, this one will have to stay as-is for the time being.

Comment: It's a pity, than now to be a grammatically correct moderators should suspend user for more than a single day, and exclude 21, 31, 41...